# Is it safe to fsck on critical disk data partition?

Tags: filesystems, ext2, ext2fsd

I have x86 based box running FreeBSD 10.1. I have made it dual boot with Red hat Linux as other OS. Now I'm migrating a UFS partition 'A' on a FreeBSD (10.1) to ext2 based partition on Linux. I'm using partition 'B' as temporary storage.

I am following below procedure.

1. In FreeBSD: I format 'B' as ext2 and move data from 'A' to 'B' using rsync. Reboot the box.
2. Box comes up with Linux. I now format 'A' as ext2 in Linux , mount B as ext2 and move data from 'B' to 'A' using rsync

Issue: Many times mount of 'B' in Linux fails and suggest to run fsck. When I run `fsck` in non-interactive mode it fails and suggest to run in manually. I cannot 'fsck' run manually as box are remotely located. Secondly I'm worried if `fsck` may lead to data loss.

Queries:

1. Why linux is asking me to run fschk? What I'm doing wrong?
2. How safe is running `fsck` on a partition? My box will not able to come up cleanly in case files are removed in the operation.
3. Is there any way to log all operation done under `fsck` that I can use for debugging

Operation done on FreeBSD:

```
#format raw partition as ext2 
mkfs.ext2  /dev/mfid0s1f

#mount newly formated partition as backup
mkdir -p /backup
mount /dev/mfid0s1f /backup 

#move data for UFS partition mounted as 'data' to ext2 partition 
rsync -a /data/*  /backup 

#reboot the box 
reboot
```

Operation done in Linux (via rc.local):

```
case 1: I try to mount 'backup' without fsck

mkdir -p /backup
mount /dev/sda8  /backup 
mount fail with suggestion to run fsck. 

case 2: I add non-interective fsck

mkdir -p /backup
e2fsck -p /dev/sda8 
fail with : /dev/sda8: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY
```

Comment: That could smell as a hardware failure, or some overlapping partitions. But it smells bad. I would recommend instead backup the data (perhaps as a `.tar.bz2` archive on some external, maybe FAT32, media; or remotely)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks for your input. I'm not suspecting HW issue. If i format same partition as ext2 in Linux  and move data I do not observe any such error.

Comment: BTW, the question is unclear. You should give in it *every command* that you have run (under BSD and under Linux) and show *exactly* the disk partitionning and the mounted file systems. The first paragraph is suspicious. `fsck` is safe and reliable (but what you did probably is not). Don't suspect `fsck` but your own actions

Comment: You may need to take a few days to learn more about OSes and filesystems. Read http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/ ; you look confused and it does not appear you are fully understanding what is happening and what have you done. You certainly need to improve your question a lot (and add much more details in it, perhaps doubling the length of your question)

Comment: Just a little side issue, why on earth are you formatting as `ext2` (rather than, say, `ext4`) in 2017?

Comment: @roaima this is from BSD ext2 page "In FreeBSD ext2, ext3 and ext4 are not different filesystems: ext2 is the base filesystem and some features from ext3 and ext4 are supported. All features in FreeBSD's implementation follow UFS semantics and this can sometimes impose important differences" 

I'm doing OS migration. Linux have ext4 native support so make sense to use ext4. but BSD is lacking in that department.

Comment: The steps a) & B) in your second paragraph are not detailed enough. You should give the exact commands (and also show your disk partitionning), e.g. I ran `foobar /dev/zwxy` on Linux then rebooted BSD on the *same* computer then ran `geedo /xyz` on BSD. On Linux look also for output of `dmesg` and for recent lines in some `/var/log/*.log` files

Comment: The question makes no mention of unmounting the EXT partition before rebooting FreeBSD.

Comment: Are you saying this is a dual boot server? Nowhere does that get made clear. In one breath you talk about UFS on FreeBSD and then you talk about ext2 on Linux. Coupled with all of that you throw in a reference to `rsync`. Please go back to your question and make it quite clear what exactly you are doing (or trying to do).

Comment: @JdeBP  I'm assuming when we issue 'reboot' all partition are unmounted by OS gracefully. Correct me if this assumption is wrong.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Will add more logs soon. My office network is under maintenance.

Comment: You need to give *all* the *exact* commands you did (not only logs)

Comment: You forgot `sync` and `umount /backup` on the BSD side, before the `reboot`

Answer (score 4):

> Why OS is asking to run `fsck`?

As some point in the past the filesystem was not unmounted cleanly. The system needs you to run `fsck` to clear up the inconsistencies.

> What I'm doing wrong? I use rsync to move data.

Conceptually you're doing nothing wrong that I can see, except that you should run `fsck` (see above). It would be good to see your `rsync` command here, too.

> How safe is running fsck? My box will not able to come up cleanly in case files are removed

The filesystem is in an inconsistent state. That might be simply that the filesystem wasn't marked as clean but is otherwise fine. At the other extreme the entire filesystem might be corrupted and you could theoretically lose everything. Most times the `fsck` only cleans out files that have already been deleted but haven't yet been removed from the filesystem.

> Is there any way to log all operation done under fsck?

There are a number of options available to you. One is to use the command in its *dry run* mode (see `man fsck` and `man e2fsck`):

```
fsck -n /dev/mfid0p7
```

I would strongly recommend you do not use the automatic recovery flag, `-p` until you are happy with the fixes it is going to make.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  So we are not suspecting ext2 implementation incompatibilities as root cause of behavior.  My migration was based on assumption that an 'ext2' partition is ext2 partition respective of which OS create or mount it. After above behavior I had doubts on my assumptions.

Comment: @SatpalPatmar does FreeBSD require an explicit unmount of filesystems before a reboot? If so this could easily be the problem

Comment: I'm not sure about that so I tried both ways I see no impact of mount/unmount. I even tried sysync;sync,syc before un-mounting. No impact again.

Answer (score 2):

> a) Why OS is asking for fsck run. What I'm doing wrong?

fsck stands for "file system consistency check".

On most systems, fsck is run at boot time if certain conditions are detected. Usually, these conditions are:

- A file system is marked as "dirty" — its written state is inconsistent with data that was scheduled to be written.
- A file system has been mounted a set number of times without being checked.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> b) How safe is running fsck? My box will not able to come up cleanly in case files are removed.

Well it depends, if you enter yes when prompted to delete a wrong inode or block, you will lose data. That is why using the `-p` option might not be ideal.

Do not run fsck on a mounted filesystem! If you run fsck on a filesystem that is currently mounted, you will (at best) receive an error message, and (at worst) corrupt your filesystem data.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> c) Is there any way to log all operation done under fsck?

For the `fsck` check at boot time, you can check `/var/log/boot.log` Maybe your OS also has a `/var/log/fsck` not every Linux flavor has it.